# Save Wav file after recording it automatically

Tags: c#, audio-recording

I don't want the user to decide which location of the wav file should be saved , and automatically save it in D:\

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialog.InitialDirectory = @"D:\CIS";
        saveFileDialog.FileName = textBox1.Text;
        Stream fileStream = saveFileDialog.OpenFile();
        this.encoder.Save(fileStream);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant you don't want to prompt the user on where to save the file, and rather just save the file directly, just do

```
using (Stream fileStream = File.Open(Path.Combine(@"D:\CIS",textBox1.Text) , FileMode.Open))
{
   this.encoder.Save(fileStream), FileMode.Open);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply open a new file with the filename that you want and write the data to it like this:

```
string filename = "d:\\file1.wav";

using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(filename))
{
    this.encoder.Save(fileStream);   
}
```